# Unable to update Ubuntu 12.04: Authentication required

Tags: updates, update-manager

I initially Checked for Updates which was successful. It responded that there were 123 Updates. After trying to update, I got the following message: `Unable to Install Available Updates unsuccessful.  Authentication required.`

My question is the following: How do I authenticate so that I can continue with the update?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

in the terminal
Let me know if that gives you any errors or if it works?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to do this via the command line:

Updates the source lists:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Upgades the software reading the source lists:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**NOTE:** You need to type `sudo` in front of the commands, because you need to get authorization to perform a user update. By typing `sudo` you are then asked to type your password in, which, typed correctly, authorizes you to proceed with updating the system.